# Selenium WebDriver is only capturing half of the screen on Edge browser in IE mode, how can I capture the whole webpage?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am running automation to open website in edge browser in IE mode as IE is decommissioned.
However,
On **edge browser in IE mode**, selenium is taking **screenshot of the half of the screen**. Not the entire page is getting captured. I have used getScreenshotAs method to capture screesnhot ,however, half screen is getting captured. In addition, I have tried Ashot library too but same result.

I am opening a website in edge browser in IE mode , however, selenium is capturing only half of the screen but not the entire page. I am using below piece of code. This resulted is only half of the screenshot but not the entire page. I have used Ashot library too but same result.

```
class Steps {
   
    public static WebDriver driver=null;
    public static void Login() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver, ", "C:\\IEDRIVER-64\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        ieOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
        ieOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
        ieOptions.ignoreZoomSettings();
        ieOptions.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
        ieOptions.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
        ieOptions.withInitialBrowserUrl("http://www.bing.com");
        ieOptions.setCapability("takeFullPageScreenshot", true);
        ieOptions.takeFullPageScreenshot();

 driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.get("http://www.bing.com");
}

    public static void CaptureScreesnhot() throws IOException {
        Date d= new Date();
        String filename= d.toString().replace(":","_").replace(" ","_") + ".png";
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("file path"+filename));
    }
```

below is the screenshot look like screenshot using selenium

[image: screenshot using selenium]

Actual screen, Please visit bing.com

Expected result to get screenshot of whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. I test it and it can capture the whole webpage. Please note to change the path to your owns:

```
InternetExplorerDriverService internetExplorerDriverService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService("E:\\webdriver");

InternetExplorerOptions internetExplorerOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
internetExplorerOptions.AttachToEdgeChrome = true;
internetExplorerOptions.EdgeExecutablePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";

InternetExplorerDriver webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(internetExplorerDriverService, internetExplorerOptions, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bing.com");
webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
Thread.Sleep(6000);
((ITakesScreenshot)webDriver).GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(@"E:\images\test.png");

webDriver.Quit();
```

Comment: Hi @Yu Zhou, first of all thank you for answering the question. however, its not working at my end .I have same code as per your suggestion with few changes in java however, its giving me same result as before.  it seems margin and border of the screenshot is coming black and only middle layout of the page is getting captured. I have tried dimesnions as well but no luck.

Comment: Which version of Selenium, IE WebDriver and Edge browser do you use?